# Delphi - convert dbedit's datasource to a string

Tags: delphi

Delphi XE3 Enterprise

I have a data field that can have multiple datasources based on current operation.

I need to read the current datasource of a dbedit and convert it to a string so I can write the current datasource to a edit field.

Comment: What do mean exactly by "read the current datasource of a dbedit"?  A TDataSource has a Name property just linke any other TComponent.  Is that what you want, and if not, what *do* you want?

Comment: I want to know the name of the datasource for the dbedit field.  Once I know the name of the fields datasource I will write it to a tedit.

Comment: So what you want is not the name of the `DataSource`, but the name of the `DataSet` that the field belongs to? You should [edit] your question to make it clear, so that others can use it in the future to find answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds from your comment that all you need is:

```
Edit1.Text := DBEdit1.DataSource.Name;
```

Or, if what you actually want is the name of the dataset connected to the DBEdit via the datasource:

```
Edit1.Text := DBEdit1.DataSource.DataSet.Name;
```

Btw, I hope you don't mind my saying, but a design in which you change the datasource associated with DBEdits, etc, sounds a bit unusual.  Anyway, that's your choice.